# serial downvoting not reverted

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes, serial-voting

I received serial downvotes on April 16th and still don't get why.
https://stackoverflow.com/users/666414/maxxyme?tab=reputation

As read in the SO/SE help [1], I waited a few days for the script to revert my reputation, but nothing happened. Then I flagged the questions & answers for review but still nothing.

After waiting for a few weeks now, I re-read the help. But as I have reputation=1 here on Meta, I can't post to the tavern to request a moderator to check in.

Should I still wait?

[1] [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)

Comment: See [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/28758/230957)

Comment: Thanks for your input. So I'll re-try Step 2. But if I still don't get anything, I should consider Step 3, contact the SE/SO team.

Comment: @3ventic am I crazy or did the OP say that she did all of that?

Comment: It's not entirely clear from your rep history that that's a case of serial downvoting. Your self-answered question has votes from at least four different users in particular - if they are sock-puppets, sure, but might not be the case.

Comment: @djechlin shows how much I skip when reading, I guess... *facepalm*

Comment: @djechlin unfortunately I did not contact SO/SE team because I felt I should do it only as a last resort.

Comment: @Mat thanks for you explanation. it's just that I found it rather strange: getting 10 downvotes on my 4 last questions in a 5 minute interval, especially after I answered my own question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23115635/how-to-reformat-a-date-into-the-iso-format-in-a-single-line

Comment: I find a rather related topic: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171443/serial-negative-group-voting

Although it's not confirmed the downvoters are related (further investigation needed), I'll try to remain vigilant regarding this kind of issues.

Answer (score 6):

Almost all of those downvotes are on [your self-answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23115635/how-to-reformat-a-date-into-the-iso-format-in-a-single-line). People may have downvoted your question and answer independently upon review.

As it is impossible for someone to vote twice on one post, that means these downvotes are from at least five unique people.

It's not inconceivable that your other two downvotes came from two different users who clicked through to your profile. Seeing as they were several minutes apart, I'm not sure it would have been enough to trip the script even if they were from the same user.

Comment: Yes, that's what I suspected, see my comment above. But what's the matter with auto-answer? Also I posted on Apr 16 at 16:57 and validated my own answer the day after!!

Comment: @maxx Accepting your own answer doesn't guarantee others will agree that it is correct. The people who saw your answer indicated it was wrong. Maybe you should check your code to see if what you're doing makes sense.

Comment: "The people who saw your answer indicated it was wrong." => I'd rather say they disagreed I chose my own answer as answer to my question. No one has commented.
That's pretty coward I think. Moreover, as they also downvoted the question, they might simply have a problem with either me or my question. But again, not comment.